# How can i access file on different server

Tags: sql-server

how can i access file on different server.means
my application is on server A.
my database is on server B
I created stored procedure in database

```
DECLARE @DatabasePath VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @DatabasePath = 'E:\ABC.xls'

DECLARE @sql      nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_1]
SELECT  *
FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
        ''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @DatabasePath + ',
        ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'') AS xlsTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Now in this procedure i want to access excel sheet that is on server A.
How can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

- The file will need to be made available on some network share: `\\server\share\ABC.xls`
- The account that SQL Server runs
  under will need access to the network
  share

Comment: can u tell me any alternative as my Application & Database are on different server.

Comment: I'm not sure you need an alternative.  It sounds like the only requirement is that SQL Server has access to read the file.  Perhaps you can clarify if you still feel that there is something I am not taking into account.

Answer (score 0):

probably this one would help you 
http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2009/01/12/sql-2005-delegation-of-windows-account-how-to-access-file.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder share on the target server.
2. Ensure that the SQL Server Service account has relevant access privileges to the target server and folder share.
3. Use a UNC path to reference the file location. For example: \\ServerName\E$\ABC.xls